# Bank Card ATM pins and probability

Tags: probability

Bank ATM cards let you choose a four digit combination of integers from 1 to 9 given $9^4 = 6561$ different choices. If a person were to try 3000 choices or more generally $x \leq 6561$ for $x \in \Bbb N$ number of choices, then what is the probability of guessing the right password.

edit: I am assuming that for x attempts that each attempt is a different password.

Comment: Will he guess different passwords every time?  Independently and uniformly at random?  Or does he accidentally have a chance of guessing the same password multiple times?

Comment: @JMoravitz edited thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a systematic way of approaching the problem. Among all possible sets of $x$ choices, how many contain the correct pin? It's ${6560 \choose {x-1}}$. How many ways are there to have $x$ choices among the $6561$? It's ${6561 \choose x}$. Then divide.

Comment: I do not quite understand your first statement :  Among all possible sets of x choices, how many contain the correct pin can you flesh this out for me thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected some errors. Now the solution should be right. Point is: consider all possible size-$x$ subsets of $\{1, 2, 3, \dots, 6561\}$. How many of these subsets contain the correct pin?

Answer (score 1):

The probability is $1-(1-\frac{1}{9^4})^n$. Let's understand this formula step-by-step.

$\frac{1}{9^4}$ is the probability guessing the code right in one attempt, so $1- \frac{1}{9^4}$ is the probability for guessing it wrong.

Then, $(1- \frac{1}{9^4})^n$ is the probability for guessing the code wrong $n$ times, so $1-(1- \frac{1}{9^4})^n$ is the probability to guess it right with at most $n$ tries.

Comment: I guess there are multiple ways to interpret the question, seeing as it was not precisely stated...

Comment: This answers the question of if he chooses passwords independently and uniformly at random *with replacement* where he can guess the same password multiple times (*even though he learned it was the incorrect password before*)

Comment: You are right, my answer is no more correct